# Magento - How to rewrite /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

Tags: magento

I want to add new field in registration form, should I rewrite /app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

If yes, how can I do this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want simple, then you can use this module from AITOC - http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_checkoutfieldsmanager.html  It allows you to add fields to the registration and store the information in the users profile.

If you're going to do it yourself, you'll have to do more than rewrite the phtml file, you'll have to create a whole extension that allows you to save the data somewhere and associate it with the users profile.